# Different entities in different stores with no relationship needs to be combined for a specific functionality in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, entity, relationship

I have two different entities in different stores of core data that get populated from two different sources in the app. There is specific column which is common in both entities.

For a specific functionality in the application, I need to combine the data. In SQL terms, it would be a join on that one column and then a certain query on the joined table.

I can't create a relationship between them since they are different stores and I can't move those entities in one store since that would break the logical separation I want.

What is the most correct best practice that is followed in such cases?

Comment: Maybe some NSPredicate factory method that takes an instance of one entity and returns a predicate for fetching object(s) of the other entity

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper type that contains both of these entities like following -

```
struct CombinedEntity {
    let entityA: EntityA
    let entityB: EntityB
}
```

From the call site, you can instantiate this type when you have both of these records available in memory. There is no other responsibility of this wrapper type than to hold these two together.

Comment: I see your point. This is similar to creating a massaged model using properties from both core data entities. But querying or searching from such a structure would be very sub-optimal.
Think of a searching scenario where I want to compare search text with some properties of entityA and some properties of entityB and then the intersection of that is the final result.

Comment: The idea is NEVER to use this for querying / searching. It is merely packaging these two into one unit. It's creation happens way later after searching/filtering has been completed. You try to search/filter based on criteria X, you prepare two separate fetch requests with that criteria to fetch results from two different stores, and then say to represent the combined results set in the list view, you create these very light-weight wrapper types so that you can create a sensible data source for that list.

Answer (score 0):

This should be no problem, because Core Data has always been designed to load multiple persistent store files into the same Core Data "stack". That's why there was always a class called `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`-- because it coordinated persistent stores. With one of those you can call `addPersistentStore` as many times as you like with different stores.

This continues with the newer `NSPersistentContainer`. It's no accident that the function you use is pluralized-- `loadPersistentStores`, with an s on the end, because you can load more than one. You do this by creating a different `NSPersistentStoreDescription` for each persistent store file and adding them to the container's `persistentStoreDescriptions` array. It will go ahead and load them all, and then any managed object contexts will fetch data from all of them.

One difference to be aware of is that with multiple stores, the completion handler that `loadPersistentStores` uses will be called multiple times, once for each persistent store.

If the different persistent stores also have different data models, Core Data can handle that too, with a little bit more setup. You can merge multiple data models into a single `NSManagedObjectModel` instance. It has initializers and convenience methods to create merged models. Depending on what seems more convenient, you can use either `mergedModel(from bundles:)` or `init?(byMerging models:?)`. Either one combines multiple data models into one. Then use the merged model object as the value of the `managedObjectModel` parameter when you create the container.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I do not think it will be possible to write a single query encompassing multiple stores. Do you think that in such requirements, we should be working with multiple fetch requests and then combine the results?

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but it absolutely is possible to do that. I would not suggest using multiple fetch requests unless you have some compelling reason that you have not mentioned in this question.

Comment: I did understand your point of loading multiple stores. I also understood that I can create a merged model from different managed model. What I fail to understand is that when my starting point is two entities in different stores without any relationship created between them, what method I will use to write a single fetch request that will operate on both of the entities?

Comment: For example, if there is an entity A with a property connectionID and another entity B in a different store with the same property connectionID. If I want to write a query something like "get all entity A for which an entity B that has same connectionID has a property X true". One way is to get all entity B first with property X as true, get list of all connectionID from that result and then get all entity A with connectionID in that list. Can you please explain what other way are you suggesting?

Comment: I see, I didn't understand that you wanted to do a single fetch request for multiple entities. That's not possible. The details about having multiple persistent stores threw me off, and are ultimately not relevant to the question since you can never do a single fetch request covering multiple unrelated entities.